# Special string mapping manipulation in C#

Tags: c#, string

I need to map a string of integer range.

if I have a `string input` and `string result`, the mapping between `string input` to `string result`:

```
1,2,3,4 ~~~~ 1-4

1,2,3,5 ~~~~ 1-3,5

1,2,3,6,7 ~~~~ 1-3,6-7

1,2,3,8,11,12 ~~~~ 1-3,8,11-12
```

There is no integer 0 and the string always has the numbers sorted from smallest --> largest.

My approach : split the string, check if the difference is 1 ore more than 1, the manipulate and append to result.  I tried but I did not get the expected result.  There is always something like `1-2, 2, 3-4...`

```
string[] inputArray = input.Split(',');
string result = null;

for (int i=0; i <inputArray.Count()-1; i++)
{
    bool isNumber1 = int.TryParse(inputArray[i], out int n1);
    bool isNumber2 = int.TryParse(inputArray[i+1], out int n2);
    if (isNumber1 && isNumber2)
    {
        if ((n2-n1)==1) 
        {
          result = result + "," + n1 + "-" + n2;
        }
        else
        {
            result = result + "," + n2;
        }
    }
}
```

Try to track 1 more

```
string[] inputArray = input.Split(',');
string result = null;

if (inputArray.Count() < 2) { return input; }


for (int i=0; i <inputArray.Count()-2; i++)
{
    bool isNumber1 = int.TryParse(inputArray[i], out int n1);
    bool isNumber2 = int.TryParse(inputArray[i+1], out int n2);
    bool isNumber3 = int.TryParse(inputArray[i+2], out int n3);

    if (isNumber1 && isNumber2 && isNumber3)
    {
        if ((n2-n1)==1 && (n3-n2)==1) 
        {
          result =  n1 + "-" + n3 + ",";
        }
        if ((n2-n1)==1 && (n3-n2)>1)
        {
            result =  n1 + "-" + n2 + "," + n3 + ",";
        }

        result = result + result;
    }
}

return result;
```

How do I get the expected result like I have with the sample mapping? My code has no error but it does not give the expected result.

Comment: Well, what is the question?

Comment: Ah - how do I get the expected result like I have with the sample mapping, my code has no error but it does not give the result.

Comment: use **continue** when the number is continuous

Comment: track **previous** number as well. once number changed attach previous number to stating number

Comment: Well, I try to track 1 more but I still some issue with the math.  My head could not get it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a complete and clean sample. It can still be optimized.

```
// inputs
var input = "1,2,3,8,11,12";

// parse them as ints (ensure they are in ascending order)
var inputParsed = input.Split(',').Select(o => Convert.ToInt32(o)).OrderBy(o=> o).ToList();

// will contain results
var results = new List<List<int>>();

// will contain the current group building
var currentGroup = new List<int>();

// while we have number to parse we add them
while (inputParsed.Any())
{
    // get the current number
    var currentNumber = inputParsed[0];

    // if the current group is empty OR if the last number in is 1 less we can group it
    if (!currentGroup.Any() || currentGroup.Last() == currentNumber - 1)
    {
        // add current number to the group
        currentGroup.Add(currentNumber);                  
    }
    else
    {
        // current number doesn't match with the group so close the
        // group as it's finished and create a new one for this number

        // add the group to the list 
        results.Add(currentGroup);

        // create a new group
        currentGroup = new List<int>();

        // add current number to the group
        currentGroup.Add(currentNumber);
    }

    // remove the input we just checked
    inputParsed.RemoveAt(0);

    // check if there is any input left, if not the current group has to be added tp the results
    if (!inputParsed.Any())
    {
        // add the group to the list 
        results.Add(currentGroup);
    }
}

// parse single number as "1" and multiple number as "1-3"
var parseGroups = new Func<List<int>, string>((group) =>
{
    if (group.Count() == 1)
    {
        return group[0].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return group[0].ToString() + "-" + group.Last().ToString();
    }
});

// parse results
var parsedResults = string.Join(",", results.Select(parseGroups));
```

Comment: thank you very much - from the code you provide, the problem really not easy. I also very appreciate the detailed comments.

Comment: @UlinkSecret I always comment each of my lines even in real production code. I serves anyone else to know what the hell is happening and it some sort of pseudo code. Side note, if you list if unordered you can order it, i'll update my answer so it always order your inputs so it's 100% accurate each time.

Answer (score 3):

If we can guarantee that all items are valid integers (`int`), then the routine can be a simple **FSM** (*Finite State Machine*):

```
private static string Process(string value) {
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

  int prior = 0;
  int current = 0;

  bool first = true;     // 1st state flag - are we at the very start of the string
  bool suspend = false;  // 2nd state flag - are we in the interval a-b 

  foreach (string item in value.Split(',')) {
    current = int.Parse(item);

    if (!first && prior + 1 == current) 
      suspend = true;
    else {
      if (suspend)
        result.Append($"-{prior}");

      result.Append(first ? $"{current}" : $",{current}");

      suspend = false;
    }

    first = false;
    prior = current;
  }

  if (suspend)
    result.Append($"-{prior}");

  return result.ToString();
}
```

Tests:

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "1,2,3,4",
    "1,2,3,5",
    "1,2,3,6,7",
    "1,2,3,8,11,12",
    "1,3,8,11,12,14,21,22,23",
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(item => $"{item, -25} -> {Process(item)}"));

  Console.WriteLine(report);
```

Outcome:

```
1,2,3,4                   -> 1-4
1,2,3,5                   -> 1-3,5
1,2,3,6,7                 -> 1-3,6-7
1,2,3,8,11,12             -> 1-3,8,11-12
1,3,8,11,12,14,21,22,23   -> 1,3,8,11-12,14,21-23
```

Comment: Thank you very much for another solution! Yes, I already make sure the string is always integers + ",", no 0 and sorted

Answer (score 1):

Its working though it has to be optimized to work with collection that can have same number 2+ times.

```
var input = "1,2,3,8,11,12";
var inputIntegers = input.Split(',').Select(o => Convert.ToInt32(o)).OrderBy(o => o).ToList();

var resultSet = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach (var i in inputIntegers)
{
  var last = resultSet.LastOrDefault();
  if (!last.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<int, int>)) && last.Value + 1 == i)
  {
      resultSet[last.Key] = i;
  }
  else
  {
      resultSet.Add(i, i);
  }
}

var parts = resultSet.Select(item =>
{
  return item.Key != item.Value ? String.Format("{0}-{1}", item.Key, item.Value) : item.Key.ToString();
});
var result = String.Join(",", parts);
Console.WriteLine(result);
// 1-3,8,11-12
```